# What time of day are games released on the 3DS eshop?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

It's technically the release day for Pokemon Battle Trozei, seeing as it is after midnight where I am. I went to the eshop, however, and while I can find the game and view its details, I can't actually purchase it yet.

That makes me wonder - is there a specific time of day after which games that are due to release on the eshop for that particular day will release?

Comment: I know Steam stuff cycles round at 6PM GMT, it may be that there's a specific time for the eshop. However eshop is a horrible tag D:

Comment: @shanodin I didn't actually mean to add it.

Comment: In Europe, it happens at 14:00 GMT, but I'm not sure about US (or Japan, for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., the eShops (3DS and Wii U) update at or around 9 A.M. Pacific Time on Thursdays. In the early days of the Wii Shop Channel, this used to occur on a Monday. Some retail games that are available for download from either shop (Mario Kart 8, Tomodachi Life, Professor Layton vs. Phoenix Wright Ace Attorney, etc.) aren't made available for release until a specified date - usually on a Friday.

Answer (score -2):

Depending which country you are in Its when its midnight for the Nintendo office there.

Comment: Do you have any proof to back this up?

Comment: I use EST in america, and they always launch apps at 2 AM. Nintendo of america is in mount time zone. Two hours behind me. So they must update the country at that time.

Comment: Nintendo of America is located in *Redmond, Washington*, which is PST - three hours behind you, so 2AM for you is *11PM* for them. It's also completely unrelated to midnight for Europe, as I mentioned two weeks ago.